# Return JSON data with predefined key Yii2

Tags: json, yii2

I use Yii2 and I created RESTful API service. But in my app I want to return JSON data with predefined key for all responses. For example:

Default respons:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Brooklyn"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Financial District"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "title": "Social District"
  }
]
```

But I want to get smth like that:

```
"data": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Brooklyn"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Financial District"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "title": "Social District"
      }
]
```

Comment: It is not a valid `json` you want to get. Post here a code of your action to figure out what you need. Maybe you should simply wrap your return into `['data' => $response]`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you wrapped your "data" object into a { } ?

Comment: Actually I just to know a possibility this way. I saw some settings in config.php, but it was a long time ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply customize rest serializer, in your controller :

```
public $serializer = [
    'class' => 'yii\rest\Serializer',
    'collectionEnvelope' => 'data',
];
```

[Read more](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-response-formatting.html#data-serializing).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!